Prove that a space is a Hilbert Space with inner product different to the usual inner product used
I'm working with following academic paper : Stability of the solutions of differential equations whose author is Bernard Beauzamy.
I'm trying prove that the two next spaces $\mathcal{B}_2$ y $P_2$ are Hilbert spaces
$ \mathcal{B}_2 $ is a space of measurable functions f in the plane, such that
\begin{equation*}
  \left( \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-r^2} |f(re^{i\theta})|^2 r dr\frac{d\theta}{\pi} \right)^{1/2} < +\infty
 \end{equation*}
equipped with the norm
\begin{equation*}
 \left\Vert f\right\Vert= \left( \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-r^2} |f(re^{i\theta})|^2 r dr\frac{d\theta}{\pi} \right)^{1/2}
 \end{equation*}
and $\mathcal{P}_2$ is the closure of the analytic polynomials for this norm and subspace of $\mathcal{B}_2$.
Both the space $\mathcal{B}_2$ and the space $\mathcal{P}_2$  are Hilbert spaces with this scalar product norm
\begin{equation*}
  \langle f,g \rangle=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-r^2}f(re^{i\theta})\overline{g(re^{i\theta})} r dr\frac{d\theta}{\pi}
 \end{equation*}
I know that a Hilbert space is a complete metric space. Therefore, I have tried to show that any sequence of generic polynomials of the form $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} a_j z^j$ with $a_j \in \mathbb{C}$ is Cauchy with respect to that norm. Then, I aimed to show that such a Cauchy sequence converges to some element of the spaces. (The usual process). However, I haven't been able to reach any good result.

This is the Segal-Bargmann space. I recommend doing some reading on that topic.

"$\mathcal{P}_2$ is the clurse of the analytic polynomials for this norm": you mean the closure? and simply of the polynomials? and closure where? (as a subspace of $\mathcal B_2$?) $\mathcal B_2$ is a Hilbert by construction (it is $L^2$ of some measure), and $\mathcal P_2$ is a Hilbert, as a closed subspace of a Hilbert. So, there is no concrete work to do.

Thank you @CameronWilliams. The paper doesn't anything  about Segal.Bargmann space. So i thinked that the author "invented" this space. I ' m going to read about the topic.

Ok the implication is direct. I thought I had to use some theorem about function spaces @AnneBauval

Nothing, I had severals windows opened in the screen. Error when i was writing it. Sorry

Yes, this is a massive oversight on the author's part. The Segal-Bargmann space and transform are extremely well known and used throughout mathematical physics and integral transform theory.

Why "oversight"? Be sure he knows it!
